# Java Scanner get number from string

Tags: java, string, int, tokenize

The string is, for example `"r1"` and I need the `1` in an `int` form

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("r1");
int result = sc.nextInt(); // should be 1
```

compiles correctly but has a runtime error, should I be using the delimiter? Im unsure what the delimiter does.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Desire behavior, a specific-enough problem, and a clear problem statement were present. This question is so straightforward, it really doesnt need the actual line of code, since we hopefully all have brains that can perform basic functions such as interpreting information presented in a written form. However, I've replaced it with an arbitrary bit of real code to appease the unimaginative.

Comment: You forgot to post probably the most important information - the error message. It says you what's wrong and you will learn what to fix or change from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's a few options. Since you literally want to *skip* the "r" then read the number, you could use [`Scanner#skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String)). For example, to skip all non-digits then read the number:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("r1");
sc.skip("[^0-9]*");
int n = sc.nextInt();
```

That will also work if there are no leading non-digits.

Another option is to use non-digits as delimiters, as you mentioned. For example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("x1 r2kk3 4 x56y 7g");
sc.useDelimiter("[^0-9]+"); // note we use + not *
while (sc.hasNextInt())
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

Outputs the six numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 56, 7.

And yet another option, depending on the nature of your input, is to pre-process the string by replacing all non-digits with whitespace ahead of time, then using a scanner in its default configuration, e.g.:

```
String input = "r1";
input = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
```

And, of course, you could always just pre-process the string to remove the first character if you know it's in that form, then use the scanner (or just `Integer#parseInt`):

```
String input = "r1";
input = input.substring(1);
```

What you do depends on what's most appropriate for your input. Replace "non-digit" with whatever it is exactly that you want to skip.

---

By the way I believe a light [scolding is in order for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8NY9.jpg):

> Im unsure what the delimiter does.

The documentation for `Scanner` [explains this quite clearly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) in the intro text, and even shows an example.

Additionally, the definition of the word "delimiter" itself is [readily available](https://www.google.com/search?q=delimiter%20definition).

Comment: Why is it that you need to use `[^0-9]+` with a plus and not a star?

What happens with a star: aa123a -> becomes 1 2 3 instead of 123.

Answer (score 0):

If the formatting is the same for all your input where the last char is the value you could use this:

```
String s = sc.nextLine()
Int i = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(s.length() -1));
```

Else you could for instance make the string a char Array, iterate trough it and check whether each char is a number.

Comment: What if the String is "r15gsi"?

Comment: @MistahFiggins I imagined the formatting would be same on all the string expected.

Comment: @Jonatan If you wanted to be *that* specific why not just `int i = 1;`, lol :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some fundamental mistakes here.

First, you say:

> `One = sc.nextInt("r1");`
>
> compiles correctly ...

No it doesn't.  If `sc` is really a `java.util.Scanner`, then there is no `Scanner.nextInt(String)` method, so that cannot compile.

The second problem is that the `hasNextXXX` and `nextXXX` methods do not parse their arguments.  They parse the characters in the scanner's input source.

The third problem is that `Scanner` doesn't provide a single method that does what you are (apparently) trying to do.

---

If you have a `String` `s` that contains the value `"r1"`,  then you don't need a `Scanner` at all.  What you need to do us something like this:

```
String s = ...
int i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1));
```

or maybe something this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("r(\\d+)").matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
}
```

... which checks that the field is in the expected format before extracting the number.

On the other hand if you are really trying to read the string from a scanner them, you could do something like this:

```
String s = sc.next();
```

and then extract the number as above.

Comment: (The OP's post was pseudo-code to illustrate the idea.)

Comment: @JasonC - Actually, he presented it as Java code.  He >>said<< that it compiled correctly.  And even as pseudo-code it is misleading because that is not remotely how `Scanner` really works.